# Django Inline with join table structure

Tags: django

So I have a DB structure like so: (ignore how i named things its a quick fake DB example things)

1. Collection: id, ...
2. List: id, title,...
3. Car: id, name, ...
4. CollectionHasList: id, collectionid, listid
5. ListHasCar: id, carid, listid

So what I am trying to do is in the django admin panel under collection/add I want to be able to fill in all of these tables instead of filling everything in individually one by one.

So the collection fields will exist as normal, but then I want to have a custom field that takes in a list title and a text area that takes in a comma delimited cardIds (cards are already created and don't need to be done through here, just list and collections) But since Collections have many lists, I want to be able to click a "add" button and generate the same custom form again to add more lists (with associated cars).

I think in the model I will be able to do the custom saving that I need, but I can't get the form to work and thats what I need most help on. Can anyone please help me! Thank you so much! I looked everyone on stack overflow and haven't found anything that can directly help me, some good points, but I still can't put it together.